# How to access the baseline comparison results in IBM Rational Doors from scripts?

Tags: ibm-doors

The background to the question is, that I would like to create software change requests from Doors requirement changes.

For this I have to get the differences of requirements between two user selectable baselines of a module in a human readable format.

In the GUI I use the "Baseline Compare" function.

How can I access these results from a script (inside or outside of Doors) in a structured format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a modified version of the baseline compare script at [this forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=363ff91f-a504-4854-9e10-ea447a0aeab5) . I haven't tried it yet, but here's the code, which does use a GUI but you should be able to redirect the input & output pretty easily:

```
// Your Company Baseline Compare with Attributes

/*
Date Posted: 16-Jan-2008 00:03
Posted By: Juergen Albrecht 
*/


/*     
// (Your Company Baseline Compare)                                        *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
//                                                                           *
// Project:         Your Company Ottobrunn                                   *
//                                                                           *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
// Module:          all modules for baseline compare                   *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
// Description:     ...                                                      *
//                                                                           *
// Functions:        compare any two baselines of the current module          *       
//               (or a baseline against the current version).             *
//               Sets a filter on objects which differ with request       *
//               to Object Heading, Object Text, Object Type and ....     *
//                                                                           *
//                                                                           *
// Copyright (C) Your Company Your Town 2005-2007 Confidential. All rights reserved.     *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
//                                                           *
// $Header: /doors/lib/dxl/addins/user/BaselineCompare.dxl Ver. 1.0     15.03.06 18:00 UID-USER $
//                                                                     *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
// $History: BaselineCompare.dxl $                                                                
// 
//*********************************  Version 1.0  ****************************
// User:                  Date:            Time:                *   
// Jürgen Albrecht (uid-al28423)   15.01.08           18:00
// Created in $/doors/lib/dxl/addins/user/BaselineCompare.dxl
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
//                                                                           *
//                                                                           *
//                                                                           *
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------*  

*/

pragma runLim, 0
////////////////////////////////////////////////////// constants for Attributes
const string DUMMY_LIST[] = {}
const string strAffectsArr[]   = {"Ch.Bars", "Ch.Date", "History"}
const string strCharacterArr[]   = {"System ", "Hidden  ", "Customised"}
const string strValidityArr[]   = {"Module  ", "Object"}
const string strPropertyArr[]   = {"Inherited", "Multi value"}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// variables for Attributes
DB dbBLCompare            = null
DBE dbeAttrDefNameList      = null
DBE dbeAttrCharacter      = null
DBE dbeAttrAffects         = null
DBE dbeAttrValidity         = null
DBE dbeAttrProperty         = null
DBE dbeAttrType            = null
DBE dbeDefaultValue         = null
DBE dbeAttrTypeList         = null
DBE dbeAttrTypeSelect      = null

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// functions for Attributes
int chopInsert2(DBE inlist, string s)
{   int no_inlist = noElems inlist
   int low = 0
   int high = no_inlist-1
   int hw = 0
   string c

   if (no_inlist == 0)
   {   insert(inlist,0,s)
      setCheck(inlist,0,false)
      return 0
   }

   while (high-low > 1)
   {   hw = low + ((high-low) / 2)
      c = get(inlist,hw)
      if (s < c)
         high = hw
      else
         low = hw
   }

   c = get(inlist,high)
   if (c < s)
   {   insert(inlist,high+1,s)
      setCheck(inlist,high+1,false)
      return high + 1
   }
   c = get(inlist,low)
   if (c > s)
   {   insert(inlist,low,s)
      setCheck(inlist,low,false)
      return low
   }
   insert(inlist,low+1,s)
   setCheck(inlist,low+1,false)
   return low+1
} // chopInsert2

void populateLstAttrDef(bool bIncludeSystemAttr)
{   AttrDef ad
   for ad in current Module do
   {   if (ad.module)
         continue
      if (!bIncludeSystemAttr)
      {   if (ad.system || ad.hidden)
            continue   
      }
      chopInsert2(dbeAttrDefNameList, ad.name "")
   }
   set(dbeAttrDefNameList, 0, true)
} // populateLstAttrDef

void doNothing(DBE dbeKlick, int iKlick)
{
} // doNothing

void cbSystemSelect(DBE dbeKlick)
{   bool bSelect = get(dbeAttrTypeSelect)
   empty (dbeAttrDefNameList)
   populateLstAttrDef (bSelect)
} // cbSystemSelect

void doSetAttrTypes(void)
{   
   AttrDef ad  = find(current Module, get(dbeAttrDefNameList, get(dbeAttrDefNameList)))
   AttrType at = find(current Module, ad.typeName "")
   string strDefVal = "", strAttrType = "", s = ""
   int iAttrChar = 0, iAttrValid = 0, iProperty = 0, iAffects = 0

   if (ad.system)
      iAttrChar = 1
   else
      iAttrChar = 4
   if (ad.hidden)
      iAttrChar = iAttrChar | 2
   set(dbeAttrCharacter, iAttrChar)

   if (ad.object)
      iAttrValid = 2
   if (ad.module)
      iAttrValid = iAttrValid | 1
   set(dbeAttrValidity, iAttrValid)

   if (ad.inherit)
      iProperty = 1
   if (ad.multi)
      iProperty = iProperty | 2
   set(dbeAttrProperty, iProperty)

   if (!ad.nobars)
      iAffects = 1
   if (!ad.nochanges)
      iAffects = iAffects | 2
   if (!ad.nohistory)
      iAffects = iAffects | 4
   set(dbeAttrAffects, iAffects)

   if ( null at )
   {   strAttrType = "Unable to determine type of attribute"
      set(dbeAttrType, strAttrType)
      return      
   }

   strAttrType = at.type ""

   if ( at.type == attrInteger ) 
   {   int i
      if ( at.minValue )
      {   i = at.minValue
         s = s "Min > " i "\n"
      }
      if ( at.maxValue ) 
      {   i = at.maxValue
         s = s "Max < " i "\n"
      }
   }
   else if ( at.type == attrReal ) 
   {   real r
      if ( at.minValue )
      {   r = at.minValue
         s = s "Min > " r "\n"
      }
      if ( at.maxValue ) 
      {   r = at.maxValue
         s = s "Max < " r "\n"
      }
   }
   else if ( at.type == attrDate ) 
   {   Date d
      if ( at.minValue )
      {   d = at.minValue
         s = s "Min > " d "\n"
      }
      if ( at.maxValue ) 
      {   d = at.maxValue
         s = s "Max < " d "\n"
      }
   }
   else if ( at.type == attrEnumeration )
   {   string strAttrTypeName = at.name
      strAttrType = strAttrType ": " strAttrTypeName
      int i
      for ( i = 0; i < at.size; ++i )
         s = s at.strings[i] "\n"
   }
   set(dbeAttrType, strAttrType)
   set(dbeAttrTypeList, s)

   if (ad.defval)
   {   if (strDefVal == "")
         strDefVal = ad.defval
      set (dbeDefaultValue, strDefVal)
   }
   else
      set (dbeDefaultValue, "")

   // Ausgabe in File
//   output << ad.name"\n"
//   output << s"\n"
} // doSetAttrTypes

void cbDoSetAttrTypes(DBE dbeKlick, int iKlick)
{   doSetAttrTypes
} // cbDoSetAttrTypes

void showAttributes()
{   if ( null current Module )
   {   ack "This tool must be run within a module..."
      halt
   }
   // Ausgabe in File
   //   output << "\t\t"(current Module)."Name""\n"

   populateLstAttrDef(true)

   doSetAttrTypes()

   //   close output
} // showAttrInvestigatorDB

/////////////////////////////////////////// Definition for Modules
DBE lblOldList, lblNewList
DBE dbeListCurrent, dbeListBaseline         // two global lists containing the baseline selected (or current version)
DBE dbeOutFileBrowse, dbeOutFileLabel
DBE dbeChangeBarToggle
DBE dbeShowDiffToggle

Stream outFile

Skip skBaselines = create                  // cache current baselines

bool bShowDiff
string strCellBorders = "\\clbrdrt\\brdrs\\brdrw15\\brdrcf11 \\clbrdrl\\brdrs\\brdrw15\\brdrcf11 \\clbrdrb\\brdrs\\brdrw15\\brdrcf11 \\clbrdrr\\brdrs\\brdrw15\\brdrcf11 "

string lastHeadingNumber(Object o)
{   Regexp reg = regexp "\\.0-[0-9]+$"
   string onum = number o
   if (onum[0:0] == "0")
   {   return "0"
   }
   else if (reg onum)
   {   int i = start 0
      string hd = onum[0:i-1]
      while (reg hd)
      {   int j = start 0
         hd = hd[0:j-1]
      }
      return hd
   }
   else
   {   return onum
   }
} // lastHeadingNumber

bool oleInsDel(Object o1,o2)
{   bool oleRec = false
   string modType = ""
   int oldOle = oleCount(o2."Object Text")
   int newOle = oleCount(o1."Object Text")

   if (newOle > oldOle)
   {   oleRec = true
      modType = "Figure/Table inserted"
   }
   if (newOle < oldOle)
   {   oleRec = true
      modType = "Figure/Table deleted"
   }
   if (oleRec)
   {   outFile << "\\trowd \\trgaph108\\trleft-108\\trkeep"
      outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx6129 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
      outFile << "\\intbl " identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\cell OLE\\cell " modType "\\cell  \\cell\\row\n"
   }
   return oleRec
} // oleInsDel

bool oleChange(Object o1,o2)
{   int i = oleCount o1."Object Text"
   if (i > 0)
   {   Buffer b1 = create
      Buffer b2 = create
      b1 = richTextWithOle o1."Object Text"
      b2 = richTextWithOle o2."Object Text"
      int l1 = length b1
      int l2 = length b2
      delete b1
      delete b2
      if (l1 != l2)
      {   outFile << "\\trowd \\trgaph108\\trleft-108\\trkeep"
         outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx6129 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
         outFile << "\\intbl " identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\cell OLE\\cell Figure/Table modified\\cell   \\cell\\row\n"
         accept o1                  // set filter
         accept o2                  // on both objects
         return true
      }
   }
   return false
} // oleChange

bool compareObjects(int absno, Object o1, o2, string attr)
{ // function to compare an attribute of two objects with same absolute number
   Buffer s1 = create
   Buffer s2 = create
   Buffer s3 = create
   s1 = o1.attr
   s2 = o2.attr
   if (s1!=s2)
   {   outFile << "\\trowd \\trgaph108\\trleft-108\\trkeep"
//      if ((attr=="Object Text") && bShowDiff)
      if (bShowDiff)
//   {
//   diff(s3, s2, s1,"\\cf1\\strike ","\\cf3\\ul ")
//   outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
//   outFile << "\\intbl \\fs16 " identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\cell " attr "\\cell " s3 "\\cell " s2 "\\cell\\row\n"
//   }

      {  diff(s3, s2, s1)
         Regexp ct = regexp "colortbl[^}]*}"
         string frag
         if (ct s3)
         {   frag = s3[end 0 + 1:(length s3) - 3]
         }
         else
         {   frag = richTextFragment stringOf(s3)
         }
         outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
         outFile << "\\intbl \\fs16 " identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\cell " attr "\\cell " frag "\\cell\\row\n"
      }
      else
      {   outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx6129 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
         outFile << "\\intbl \\fs16 " identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\cell " attr "\\cell " s1 "\\cell " s2 "\\cell\\row\n"
      }
      accept o1                  // set filter
      accept o2                  // on both objects
      delete s1
      delete s2
      delete s3
      return false
   }
   delete s1
   delete s2
   delete s3
   return true
} // compareObjects

Skip getAbsnos(Module m)
{ // Build a skip list which maps absnos onto their corresponding objects.  Also initialize the DXL filter to "reject"
   Skip res = create
   Object o
   for o in m do
   {   int a = o."Absolute Number"
      reject o                  // filter those mentioned in report
      put(res, a, o)
   }
   return res
} // getAbsnos

void applyCompareFunction (DB dbKlick)
{ // Main comparison routine:   find out which modules to compare
   //                     compare objects present in both, report on
   //                     those present in only one.
   string name1, name2, outf
   int idx1, idx2
   bool updateChangeBars
   idx1 = get dbeListCurrent            // position in list
   idx2 = get dbeListBaseline
   name1 = get dbeListCurrent            // baseline name
   name2 = get dbeListBaseline
   outf = get dbeOutFileBrowse
   updateChangeBars = get dbeChangeBarToggle
   bShowDiff = get dbeShowDiffToggle

   if (idx1 < 0 || idx2 < 0)      // error checking
   {   ack "two selections are needed"
      return
   }
   else if (idx1 == idx2)
   {   ack "same selection on both sides"
      return
   }

   Regexp slash = regexp "[\\\\]"
   if (!slash outf)
   {   outf = currentDirectory "\\" outf
   }

   Baseline sel1, sel2

   outFile = write outf
   outFile << "{\\rtf1\\deff0{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset177 Times New Roman;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red0\\green255\\blue0;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}\n"
   outFile << "\\paperw11906\\paperh16838\\margl1134\\margr567\\margt1134\\margb851\\headery567\\footery567\n"
   string where = (current Module)."Name"
   outFile << "\\ul \\fs24 Modified Objects in Module: " where "\\ul0 \\par \\par\n"
   outFile << "\\trowd \\trgaph108\\trleft-108\\trhdr"
   outFile << strCellBorders "\\cellx1026 " strCellBorders "\\cellx2727 " strCellBorders "\\cellx6129 " strCellBorders "\\cellx9531\n"
   outFile << "\\intbl \\fs20 Identifier\\cell Attribute\\cell Current Baseline\\cell Old Baseline\\cell\\row\n"

   string str
   for str in skBaselines do            // find each baseline
   {   Baseline b = key skBaselines      // the baseline is the key
      string str = (major b) "." (minor b) (suffix b)
      if (name1==str) sel1 = b
      if (name2==str) sel2 = b
   }

   progressStart(dbBLCompare, "Baseline Compare", "", 1)
   Module old = current
   Module b1, b2
   if (idx1==0)
      b1 = old                  // i.e. the current Module
   else
   {   progressMessage("Load First Baseline Module")
      b1 = load(sel1, true)         // load the baselines on the screen
   }
   progressStop()

   progressStart(dbBLCompare, "Baseline Compare", "", 1)
   if (idx2==0)
      b2 = old                  // i.e.e the current Module
   else
   {   progressMessage("Load Second Baseline Module")
      b2 = load(sel2, true)
   }
   progressStop()

   if (updateChangeBars and (idx1 == 0))
   {   AttrDef atcb
      atcb = find(b1,"ChangeBar")
      if (null atcb)
      {   updateChangeBars = false
         ack "No ChangeBar attribute in current module"
      }
      else
      {   atcb = find(b1,"WordDocChangeLog")
         if (!null atcb)
         {   b1."WordDocChangeLog" = outf
         }
      }
   }
   else if (updateChangeBars)
   {   updateChangeBars = false
      ack "Can only update ChangeBar in current module"
   }

   Skip skCompAttributes = create
   string aName
   AttrDef atb1,atb2
   int i, iSkip = 0, iElems = noElems (dbeAttrDefNameList)
   bool bCheck
   for (i=0;i<iElems;i++)
   {   bCheck = getCheck (dbeAttrDefNameList, i)
      if (bCheck)
      {   aName = get (dbeAttrDefNameList, i)
         atb1 = find(b1,aName)
         atb2 = find(b2,aName)
         if ((null atb1) or (null atb2))
         {   if (null atb1)
               infoBox aName " not in later baseline"
            else
               infoBox aName " not in earlier baseline"
         }
         else
            put(skCompAttributes, iSkip++, aName)
      }
   }

   current = b1               // make sure filtering is off
   filtering off               // on both sides.
   current = b2
   filtering off
   current = old
   Skip absno1 = getAbsnos b1      // build caches of absnos -> objects
   Skip absno2 = getAbsnos b2
   Object o1, o2
   int iObj=0, iMaxObj=0, diffs=0
   bool StartInsert = true

   for o1 in absno1 do            // loop through side 1
      iMaxObj++
   progressStart(dbBLCompare, "Baseline Compare", "", iMaxObj)
   progressMessage("Compare selected attributes of all objects by Identifier")
   for o1 in absno1 do            // loop through side 1
   {   progressStep(iObj++)
      Object o2
      int i = (int key absno1)

      if (find(absno2, i, o2))   // absno exists in other baseline
      {   bool ChangeFound = false
         for aName in skCompAttributes do
         {   ChangeFound = !compareObjects(i, o1, o2, aName) || ChangeFound
         }
         ChangeFound = oleInsDel(o1,o2) || ChangeFound

         if (!ChangeFound)
         {   ChangeFound = oleChange(o1,o2)
         }

         if (ChangeFound)
         {   diffs++            // found a difference
            if (updateChangeBars)
            {   o1."ChangeBar" = true
            }
         }
         else if (updateChangeBars)
         {   o1."ChangeBar" = false
         }
         delete(absno2, i)      // remove from dbeListBaseline
      }
      else
      {   if (StartInsert)
         {   outFile << "\\pard\\par\\ul \\fs24 Inserted Objects\\ul0\\par \\par "
            StartInsert = false
         }
         outFile << "\\fs20" identifier(o1) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o1) "\\par "
         accept o1
         if (updateChangeBars)
         {   o1."ChangeBar" = true
         }
         diffs++
      }
   }
   progressStop()
   raise (dbBLCompare)
   infoBox "Baseline Compare has finished"

   if (StartInsert)
   {   outFile << "\\pard\\par\\ul \\fs24 Inserted Objects\\ul0\\par \\par "
   }
   outFile << "\n\\par\\ul \\fs24 Deleted Objects\\ul0\\par \\par "

   for o2 in absno2 do            // now we can check for objects not in dbeListCurrent
   {   int i = (int key absno2)
      outFile << "\\fs20" identifier(o2) " section " lastHeadingNumber(o2) "\\par "
      accept o2
      diffs++
   }
   delete absno1               // delete caches
   delete absno2
   delete skCompAttributes
   bool doFilter               // set to true if differences

   if (diffs==0)
   {   outFile << "\n\\par \\fs24 no differences found\\par "
      doFilter=false
   }
   else                     // set filtering on in baselines
   {   if (diffs==1)
         outFile << "\n\\par \\fs24 one difference found\\par "
      else
         outFile << "\n\\par \\fs24 " diffs " differences found\\par "
      doFilter=true
   }

   outFile << "\\par }"
   close(outFile)
   current = b1               // set filters
   if (b1 != old)
      close b1
//   filtering doFilter
//   refresh current
   current = b2
   if (b2 != old)
      close b2
//   filtering doFilter
//   refresh current
   current = old               // return to former current module
} // applyCompareFunction

//// MAIN PROGRAM ////////////////////////

Module m = current      // check calling context
if (null m)
{   ack "program requires current Module"
   halt
}

Baseline b
int i=0
for b in m do   // count number of baselines
{   i++
}
if (i==0)
{   ack "no baselines to compare"
   halt
}

// Now make a dialog for selecting two baselines for comparison
string where = (current Module)."Name"
dbBLCompare = create "Your Company Baseline Compare V. 1.0 startet at Module: \"" where "\""
string strEmptyArr[] = {}
dbeListCurrent = list(dbBLCompare, "Current/Baseline:", 300, i+1 <? 5, strEmptyArr)   // make maximum size of 5 elements
dbeListCurrent->"right"->"unattached"         // make lists side by side

dbeListBaseline = list(dbBLCompare, "Baseline to compare with:", 300, i+1 <? 5, strEmptyArr)
dbeListBaseline->"left"->"flush"->dbeListCurrent
dbeListBaseline->"top"->"aligned"->dbeListCurrent
dbeListBaseline->"right"->"unattached"

separator (dbBLCompare)

dbeAttrDefNameList = listView(dbBLCompare, listViewOptionCheckboxes   , 250, 14, DUMMY_LIST)
dbeAttrDefNameList->"left"->"form"
dbeAttrDefNameList->"right"->"unattached"

dbeAttrAffects = checkBox(dbBLCompare, "", strAffectsArr, 0)
dbeAttrAffects->"top"->"aligned"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrAffects->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrAffects->"right"->"unattached"
inactive (dbeAttrAffects)

dbeAttrCharacter = checkBox(dbBLCompare, "", strCharacterArr, 0)
dbeAttrCharacter->"top"->"flush"->dbeAttrAffects
dbeAttrCharacter->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrCharacter->"right"->"unattached"
inactive (dbeAttrCharacter)

dbeAttrValidity = checkBox(dbBLCompare, "valid for:         ", strValidityArr, 0)
dbeAttrValidity->"top"->"flush"->dbeAttrCharacter
dbeAttrValidity->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrValidity->"right"->"unattached"
inactive (dbeAttrValidity)

dbeAttrProperty = checkBox(dbBLCompare, "Properties:      ", strPropertyArr, 0)
dbeAttrProperty->"top"->"flush"->dbeAttrValidity
dbeAttrProperty->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrProperty->"right"->"unattached"
inactive (dbeAttrProperty)

dbeAttrType = field   (dbBLCompare, "Type: ", "", 27, true)
dbeAttrType->"top"->"spaced"->dbeAttrProperty
dbeAttrType->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrType->"right"->"unattached"

dbeDefaultValue = field   (dbBLCompare, "Default value:", "", 21, true)
dbeDefaultValue->"top"->"flush"->dbeAttrType
dbeDefaultValue->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeDefaultValue->"right"->"unattached"


dbeAttrTypeList = text(dbBLCompare, "Possible values or defined borders:", "", 215, 142, true) 
dbeAttrTypeList->"top"->"spaced"->dbeDefaultValue
dbeAttrTypeList->"left"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrTypeList->"right"->"unattached"
//dbeAttrTypeList->"bottom"->"unattached"

dbeAttrTypeSelect = toggle(dbBLCompare,"show System and Hidden Attributes", true)
dbeAttrTypeSelect->"top"->"flush"->dbeAttrDefNameList
dbeAttrTypeSelect->"left"->"form"
dbeAttrTypeSelect->"right"->"unattached"
dbeAttrTypeSelect->"bottom"->"unattached"

separator (dbBLCompare)

dbeOutFileLabel = label(dbBLCompare, "Output to:")
dbeOutFileBrowse = fileName(dbBLCompare, "D:\\Project - DOORS Demonstration\\BL_Comp_Result.rtf", "*.rtf", "Rich Text files", false)

dbeChangeBarToggle = toggle(dbBLCompare,"Update ChangeBar attribute", false)
beside (dbBLCompare)
dbeShowDiffToggle = toggle(dbBLCompare,"Show Object Text changes as markup", true)

// dummy
DBE dbeDummy = label(dbBLCompare, "")
dbeDummy->"top"->"spaced"->dbeShowDiffToggle
dbeDummy->"left"->"form"
// Copyright
DBE dbeCopyRight = label(dbBLCompare, "Copyright (C) Your Company Your Town 2005-2007 Confidential. All rights reserved.")
dbeCopyRight->"bottom"->"spaced"->dbeDummy
dbeCopyRight->"left"->"form"

apply(dbBLCompare, "Compare Now", applyCompareFunction)

set(dbeAttrDefNameList, cbDoSetAttrTypes, doNothing, doNothing)
set(dbeAttrTypeSelect, cbSystemSelect)

realize (dbBLCompare, 0, 0)                     // we realize so that the lists can be populated using insert

insertColumn(dbeAttrDefNameList, 0, "Attribute Name", 200, iconNone)

for b in m do                  // fill up the baselines skip list with current baselines
{   string str = (major b) "." (minor b) (suffix b)
   put(skBaselines, b, str)
   insert(dbeListCurrent, 0, str)
   insert(dbeListBaseline, 0, str)
}
insert(dbeListCurrent, 0, "current")         // put current at head of lists
set(dbeListCurrent, 0)
insert(dbeListBaseline, 0, "current")
set(dbeListBaseline, 1)
showAttributes()

show dbBLCompare                        // off we go.......
// end of BaselineCompare.dxl
```

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point might the Doors DXL library Tools -> DXL Library -> baseline comparator example, but it needs heavy modifications for your overall use-case I guess. Take a look.