# Why does DOORS `isBaseline` seem to always return FALSE?

Tags: versioning, ibm-doors, baseline

I  created a new major baseline in a DOORS module and then ran a small DXL script which includes lines

```
 Module mp = current
Baseline bp = getMostRecentBaseline(mp)
int majorVersion = major(bp)
int minorVersion = minor(bp)
print "major " majorVersion " minor " minorVersion "\n"
string suff = suffix(bp)
print "suffix " suff "\n"
bool bstat
bstat = isBaseline(mp)
print "bstat " bstat "\n"
ModuleVersion mv = moduleVersion(mp)
string basind = baselineIndex(mp)
print "baseline index " basind "\n"
bool otherbstat = baseline(mp)
print "otherstat " otherbstat "\n"
bool basv = isBaseline(mv)
print "version base " basv "\n"
```

All of these return FALSE, indicating the module is not currently baselined.  I have not done any edits to any attributes since baselining.  I have done things like creating new Views.  If I run the IBM DXL macro to compare the latest baseline against the "Current" version,  it reports there are zero differences.

So my question is - what do the various `isBaseline` functions look at that is causing them to return FALSE?  Or, am I going about this the wrong way - all I really need is a Q&D bit of DXL code to check that my module hasn't been edited for content since the last baseline was established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that when your code gets a ModuleVersion (line 11), it uses a form of the function that gets the current version of the module. Line 14 should invoke **isBaseline**, not **baseline**, making the last two lines redundant.

See p310 of the current version (9.6.1) of the DXL Reference Manual for full details of the **moduleVersion** function.

The minimally modified version of your code that gets the result I think you were expecting, follows:

```
Module mp = current
Baseline bp = getMostRecentBaseline(mp)
int majorVersion = major(bp)
int minorVersion = minor(bp)
print "major " majorVersion " minor " minorVersion "\n"
string suff = suffix(bp)
print "suffix " suff "\n"
bool bstat
bstat = isBaseline(mp)
print "bstat " bstat "\n"
ModuleVersion mv = moduleVersion(uniqueID(mp), bp)
string basind = baselineIndex(mp)
print "baseline index " basind "\n"
bool otherbstat = isBaseline(mv)
print "otherstat " otherbstat "\n"
bool basv = isBaseline(mv)
print "version base " basv "\n"
```

In the version below, I've renamed variables, reordered some lines, and removed some content that wasn't required, for clarity:

```
Module modCurrent   = current
Baseline blLatest   = getMostRecentBaseline(modCurrent)

int iMajorVersion   = major(blLatest)
int iMinorVersion   = minor(blLatest)

string sBLSuffix    = suffix(blLatest)

print "last baseline: major " iMajorVersion " minor " iMinorVersion " suffix " sBLSuffix "\n"

bool bIsBaseline = isBaseline(modCurrent)

print "bIsBaseline = " bIsBaseline "\n"

ModuleVersion mv    = moduleVersion(uniqueID(modCurrent), blLatest)
Module modBaselined = load(mv, false)

string basind = baselineIndex(modBaselined)

print "baseline index = " basind "\n"

bIsBaseline = isBaseline(modBaselined)

print "bIsBaseline = " bIsBaseline "\n"

close(modBaselined)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had provided redundant approaches just to show they all seemed to derive the same result.  Your code is helpful

Comment: Ah, makes sense. You’re most welcome, Carl. Would you please click the ‘up’ arrow next to my answer to record a ‘vote’ for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `isBaseline` returns TRUE only if the current module View is set to display a selected baseline, as opposed to the "current" working view.  `isBaseline and its brethren do  not look at module contents, and thus won't see  any potential differences between a baseline version and the current working view.

I'm aware of various DXL tools which perform a 'compare' on the contents, so that can be dealt with separately.  As noted at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825968/how-to-access-the-baseline-comparison-results-in-ibm-rational-doors-from-scripts/52101114#52101114), there are enhanced versions of the default "compare" script, such as one posted at [this DOORS forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=363ff91f-a504-4854-9e10-ea447a0aeab5)