# How to Compare 2 modules in DOORS?

Tags: object, module, scripting, compare, ibm-doors

I am trying to compare 2 modules based on their attributes which are Object ID, Object Text, InLinks, and OutLinks.
Is there any short/quick way to achieve this ? Or do I have to search for objects one by one in modules using for loop ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this post [How to access the baseline comparison results in IBM Rational Doors from scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825968/how-to-access-the-baseline-comparison-results-in-ibm-rational-doors-from-scripts) may help you. Otherwise the differences column or the baseline comparison script at smartdxl.com might help you if you adopt it to your needs.
There is one professional solution that I know of, the comparison part of "BranchManager for DOORS"